# How to restore the session from keras training model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to restore the session from keras training model.

I tried to restore it through following process.

1,Create checkpoint file trained by keras

```
from keras.models import *
import keras.backend as K
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

model = VGG16_convolutions()
model.fit_generator(...)

with tf.Session() as ksess:
ksess = K.get_session()
saver.save(ksess, "./ksess.cpkt", global_step=0, latest_filename="checkpoint_state")
```

2,Restore the session of tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope("block1_conv1"):
    block1_conv1_kernel = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, name="kernel")
    block1_conv1_bias = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, name="bias")
with tf.name_scope("block1_conv2"):
    block1_conv2_kernel = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, name="kernel")
    block1_conv2_bias = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, name="bias")
...

sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("ksess.ckpt-0.meta")
saver.restore(sess, "./ksess.ckpt")
```

So, how can I restore session from keras training model?

Best regards.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, you try googling your question. keras.io -> FAQ gives you all necessary information.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  Just you said, it's described the way to save the model of keras. But I can't restore the session using them.

Comment: Google now points to this question as the first hit, so it might be worth answering anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There already some answered questions similar to yours, I would recommend you to google them first. But if none of them works, maybe you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763094/how-to-save-final-model-using-keras) one and try to save your model and use it in another session.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think that they are described only the situation that inferenced by keras and trained by keras. I would like to inference by tensorflow after trained by keras.