# How can I modify ModelCheckPoint in keras to monitor both val_acc and val_loss and save accordingly the best model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

`ModelCheckPoint` gives options to save both for `val_Acc` and `val_loss` separately. 
I want to modify this in a way so that if `val_acc` is improving -> save model. if `val_acc` is equal to previous best `val_acc` then check for `val_loss`, if `val_loss` is less than previous best `val_loss` then save the model.

```
    if val_acc(epoch i)> best_val_acc:
        save model
    else if val_acc(epoch i) == best_val_acc:
        if val_loss(epoch i) < best_val_loss:
           save model
        else
           do not save model
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just add two callbacks:

```
callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint(filepathAcc, monitor='val_acc', ...),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepathLoss, monitor='val_loss', ...)]

model.fit(......., callbacks=callbacks)
```

### Using custom callbacks

You can do anything you want in a `LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=saveModel)`.

```
best_val_acc = 0
best_val_loss = sys.float_info.max 

def saveModel(epoch,logs):
    val_acc = logs['val_acc']
    val_loss = logs['val_loss']

    if val_acc > best_val_acc:
        best_val_acc = val_acc
        model.save(...)
    elif val_acc == best_val_acc:
        if val_loss < best_val_loss:
            best_val_loss=val_loss
            model.save(...)
    
callbacks = [LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=saveModel)]
```

But this is nothing different from a single `ModelCheckpoint` with `val_acc`. You won't really be getting identical accuracies unless you're using very few samples, or you have a custom accuracy that doesn't vary much.

Comment: that should be it.

Comment: I have added two callbacks already(for now). But that wouldn't do what I want. Both callbacks will save weights based on either lowest loss or highest accuracy. But not according to my problem (as mentioned in question).

Comment: That's perfect!! Thank you so much. Yes, I have less test samples that's why I am getting same accuracy again and again. @DanielMöller

Comment: Also it needs a small modification. `best_val_loss` should be updated after first `if` .. `best_val_loss = val_loss`

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. This is great! thanks @DanielMöller

Answer (score -1):

You can actually check in their documentation!

<del>to save you some time though, the callback, `ModelCheckpoint` accepts an argument called `save_best_only` which does what you want to happen, just set it to `True`. here's the link of the documentation</del>

I misunderstood you're question. I guess if you want a more complex type of callback you could always use the base `Callback` function, which gives you more power since you could access both `parmas` and `model`. Check the [docu](https://keras.io/callbacks/) out. You can start by testing it out and printing the params and determine which one you'd want to take note of.

Comment: I am new to keras and trying to find out how to modify ModelCheckPoint class in keras. I tried searching on net questions regarding modelcheckpoint or if someone has modified this class. Couldn't get any success. If you have any reference please paste the link. Thanks

Comment: As ive said. If you want more power for you're callback in building the model, it would be best for you to use the base `Callback` function. I added the link on the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. It can be a way too for my problem. But I find LambdaCallback more easy.

Answer (score -1):

Check out ModelCheckPoint in [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/).
`model.fit()` method takes as a parameter the callback list. Make sure you have something like:

`model.fit(..., callbacks=[mcp] )` where `mcp = ModelCheckPoint()` as defined.

Note: You may have multiple callbacks in the callback list.

For clarity I am adding some details but effectively this will do the same as [model.save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763094/how-to-save-final-model-using-keras/53734198#53734198) function:

```
class ModelCheckpoint(Callback):
    """Save the model after every epoch.
    `filepath` can contain named formatting options,
    which will be filled the value of `epoch` and
    keys in `logs` (passed in `on_epoch_end`).
    For example: if `filepath` is `weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5`,
    then the model checkpoints will be saved with the epoch number and
    the validation loss in the filename.
    # Arguments
        filepath: string, path to save the model file.
        monitor: quantity to monitor.
        verbose: verbosity mode, 0 or 1.
        save_best_only: if `save_best_only=True`,
            the latest best model according to
            the quantity monitored will not be overwritten.
        mode: one of {auto, min, max}.
            If `save_best_only=True`, the decision
            to overwrite the current save file is made
            based on either the maximization or the
            minimization of the monitored quantity. For `val_acc`,
            this should be `max`, for `val_loss` this should
            be `min`, etc. In `auto` mode, the direction is
            automatically inferred from the name of the monitored quantity.
        save_weights_only: if True, then only the model's weights will be
            saved (`model.save_weights(filepath)`), else the full model
            is saved (`model.save(filepath)`).
        period: Interval (number of epochs) between checkpoints.
    """
```

Comment: I understand ModelCheckPoint class. And I know that one can give multiple callbacks in model.fit(). I want to judge model based on both val_acc and val_loss and then save accordingly.