# How to save different keras model into one .h5py

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to do video classification using Conv2D and LSTM. After getting the features from Conv2D I pass them to LSTM. As they are two different models how can I merge them into one for getting a single .h5py?

And also the features from Conv2D are passed to LSTM as sequences of frames saved as ".npy" array files.

I need to save the model for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using tf keras for merge you can use [this](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) method:

```
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[Conv2D, LSTM], outputs=out)
```

And to save your model you can just use .save as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763094/how-to-save-final-model-using-keras)

```
model.save('your_model.h5')
```

Not exactly sure if this is what you need but hope it helps.